# No user search option on Users page of data.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, data-explorer, users

On [users page](https://data.stackexchange.com/users) of data.stackexchange.com there is no search box [except the default one which will search for queries]. Why there is no search option on this page?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that was rather annoying wasn't it?

Thankfully, there now [is a search](https://data.stackexchange.com/users) on the users page, as well as an "active" tab for good measure.